# Random Variable Distribution (Successive Removal from List)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary list with $n$ distinct elements.  Suppose I have a separate list, $B$, which is initially identical to $A$.  Denote individual elements in $B$ as $b_k$ where $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.  Now suppose I perform an experiment in which I randomly choose an element from $B$ (each element in $B$ is chosen with fixed, non-zero probability $P_{b_k}$ where $\sum_{k=1}^n P_{b_k}=1$), remove the corresponding element from $A$, and then continue until $A$ is empty.  Since items were not removed from $B$, an already-removed item from $A$ could be chosen again.  Let the random variable $X$ be the number of attempts it takes to empty the list $A$.  What is the distribution of $X$ as dependent on $n$ and the $b_k$?

We know that the support of $X$ is $\{n,n+1, n+2, ...\}$, but it seems very confusing to assign these probabilities for each $X$, especially since each element in $B$ is not equally likely to be chosen.  What is the probability mass function of $X$?  I think that this is a similar problem to the "Coupon collector's problem," except here the probabilities aren't equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a generalization of the coupon collector's problem. I strongly suspect that any attempt to write down the entire probability distribution for $X$ will be cumbersome and unenlightening. Here's a question whose accepted answer shows how to calculate the expectation of $X$: [Non-standard coupon collector's problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037142)

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) on the coupon collector's problem provides this expression for the expectation of $X$:

$$
E(X)=\int_0^\infty \big(1-\prod_{k=1}^n(1-e^{-P_{b_k}t})\big)\mathrm dt\;.
$$

It's quoted from [Flajolet, Philippe; Gardy, Danièle; Thimonier, Loÿs (1992), “Birthday paradox, coupon collectors, caching algorithms and self-organizing search”, Discrete Applied Mathematics, 39 (3): 207–229, doi:10.1016/0166-218X(92)90177-C, MR 1189469](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/alloc2.ps.gz).

[Here's another article](http://mat.uab.cat/matmat/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf) that derives the same result and also has all sorts of other interesting stuff about the coupon collector's problem.

As far as I can tell, neither of these articles tries to set up the entire probability distribution for $X$.